# Firebase Question - Wanting to become an Organisation Admin

Tags: firebase

Trying to become an Organisation Admin  but can't seem to do it as an Editor. The Project Owner no longer works on the project. How do I access the project as an Editor if Im not an Admin - or how can I become the Admin?

Comment: Afaik you can't. You need the Owner/Admin to grant you the privilege.

Comment: So you can't reclaim it in any way if the Owner is just not contactable? Any suggestions?

Comment: As far as I know you cant do that on firebase console. You may try to contact google support to see if they able to help you with anything.